# CSS How do I make my div elements lineup perfectly so that collectively they make up a perfect rectangle?

Tags: styling

While I am open to any solution, counting tables, Bootstrap and Flexbox, a purely CSS solution using just div elements is greatly appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<div class="sentence-summary">
    <div class="stat bookmarked">
        <i class="fas fa-bookmark"></i>
        <span class="count">999</span>
    </div>
    <div class="stat upvotes">
        <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>
        <span class="count">999</span>
    </div>
    <div class="stat downvotes">
        <i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i>
        <span class="count">999</span>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <p>{{ $sentence->body }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.sentence-summary {
  div {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .stat {
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;

    span {
      display: block;
      font-size: 10px;
    }

    &.bookmarked {
      background-color: red;
    }
    &.upvotes {
      background-color: blue;
    }
    &.stat.downvotes {
      background-color: pink;
    }
  }
  .main {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

**Current Result**
[image]

**Desired Result**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a grid layout for this. You can specify that the first three columns (stats) should be 40px wide. And then use '1fr' to say that the 'main' sections should take up the remaining space. Using a grid means that the heights will stay the same.

You can use 'grid-column-gap' to specify the amount of space you would like between each column. Something like this:

```
.sentence-summary {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 40px 40px 40px 1fr;
    column-gap: 5px;
    grid-auto-rows: 40px;
}
```

Make sure you use the appropriate browser prefixes as this syntax isn't supported by all browsers. I usually use [this auto-prefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).

**Update:** Adding grid-auto-rows: 40px; makes sure your 'stats' stay square!

Comment: I made a codepen for you as a demo: https://codepen.io/newstaircase/pen/gOLbwGd

Comment: I would also recommend using flex on the 'stats' divs, to achieve easy vertical and horizontal centring.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way I can prevent the text inside the green div from leaking out? I want the height of the ```.sentence-summary``` div to adjust itself to accommodate for longer texts.

Comment: You're welcome :-) If you remove the 'grid-auto-rows: 40px', then the height wont be fixed to 40px and just adapt to accommodate. If you want all the rows to be the same height (the height of the largest), use 'grid-auto-rows: 1fr'